# Refactor sharedpreference keys but preserve their values in Android

Tags: android, refactoring, sharedpreferences

I have released my app to the market and I'm preparing an update.

However, I wanted to refactor the key name of some shared preference but retain the current value on the user's device. Another thing is that I also want to delete the old key name (so the SharedPreferences file is not polluted with unnecessary keys.

How can I achieve this without any hassle to my users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of all of your preference keys

Create an array of all the new preference keys

Then create and array of all of their values.

Then call SharedPreferences.clear(). This will completely remove all keys and values from the preferences.

The step through all values and place them back into the SharedPreferences by their new key.

Comment: I don't see how keeping preferences keys as XML string resources would help with all the requirements described in the question. I mean, that wouldn't help preserving the previous value. For that, I would still need to do something like you described on your first paragraph. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RicardoAmaral I cleaned up my answer.

Comment: But I should do that only when I detected that a user was running a previous version and updated to the new version where some preference key was changed, right? Please note that I'm also only talking about a SINGLE preference key. My app doesn't have preferences at all, I haven't had the time to code them yet. This preference is what controls the latest version installed (so I can show a changelog on startup if the user updated to a new version). It's just that I like to follow conventions, even if they are my own and I want to rename that changelog preference.

Comment: Correct, only when you detect a legacy version of your app. Other then that, was I have said above will work.